# how to center gratient text to middle of line and not left

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day, I am new to flutter and i was trying something but I fail, I would like to center this login gradient text but I keep getting errors ...currently it displays at the left side as default. How do you center it? I have included the widget class and the class to display all widgets

```
     _loginGradientText() {
    
        return GradientText('mySSC',
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(89, 46, 46, 0.8),
              Color.fromRGBO(89, 46, 46, 0.8),
    
            ],),
    
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2',fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
    
      }
```

The code below to displays all the widgets created for this screen widgets

```
    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
      TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();
      FocusNode _emailFocusNode = new FocusNode();
      FocusNode _passFocusNode = new FocusNode();
      String _email, _password;
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      Screen size;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        size = Screen(MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size);
    
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            body: AnnotatedRegion(
              value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                  statusBarColor: backgroundColor,
                  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
                  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
                  systemNavigationBarColor: backgroundColor),
    
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: SafeArea(
                  top: true,
                  bottom: false,
                  child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: <Widget>[
    
    
                  ClipPath(
                  clipper: BottomShapeClipper(),
                  child: Container(
                      color: colorCurve,
                      )),
                        SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.getWidthPx(20),
                            vertical: size.getWidthPx(20)),
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              _socialButtons1(),
                              _loginGradientText(),
                              SizedBox(height: size.getWidthPx(10)),
                              _textAccount(),
                              SizedBox(height: size.getWidthPx(30)),
                              loginFields()
                            ]),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the gradient at the center and have it move outwards in all directions you can use [RadialGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RadialGradient-class.html) instead of LinearGradient.